# Using a Raster image in QGIS report linked to a field automatically switches back to SVG and doesn't display the image

Tags: qgis, reports

I have a layer setup in QGIS which stores all the information from field collection including images.  So I have image 1 to image 15.  In the QGIS Report composer you select a layer then it will print a report for all the items in that layer.  I want this report to display images that the file paths are stored in the fields.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Soon as you click that it defaults to a SVG image not a raster and give an error saying it can't display the image and you cannot select raster.  I'm using QGIS 3.16.4 and the images are .jpg.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

Comment: Tried QGIS 3.16.5 and 3.18 and same issue came up.  Do older version work?

Comment: This cannot be used linking images to fields.  Its best to use the atlas and rule based layer styling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much looking and trying different things and even using older versions the report will not print .jpg images linked from a field properly.  I did get it to print but all the images were there but blank white spaces.

The better solution for this I found is to label the layer with a rule based layer styling that is a raster image scaled based on a distance between points to avoid overlap.  Multiple images can be placed with multiple rules by using different point offsets.

[image]
[image]